# Webdev - datepicker GUI recommendations/inspiration

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

As a user, I generally don't like working with calendar GUI (e.g. on airline booking pages).  Too often, they feel clunky, difficult, and unfriendly.

I'm coding a calendar now (again) and I'm looking for inspiration and great examples.  Does the SO community have any recommendations?

(I'm looking mainly for user friendliness and ease of use, rather than slick graphics.)

*Update*

I really like this calendar: http://book.harbour-plaza.com/en/reservations_check.asp?Hotel_id=hpme - user friendly and slick graphics!

Comment: i use jquery ui datepicker, guess SO also use the same.

Comment: Are you looking for a calendar or a simple datepicker, because after rereading your question I do think you're looking for the latter...

Comment: @wimvds - datepicker, singly and in ranges, that I can adopt and modify to my purpose.  Wasn't sure of the terminology, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the JQuery UI DatePicker, very customisable for functionality and a choice of themes if you don't want to create your own.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: +1 this is a good start.  Will let the answer float for a few days and see if any better options come up before accept.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what type of calendar exactly. There are two I like, one weekly and another monthly.

[Weekly](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html)

[Monthly](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

Both are jQuery.

Comment: As a side note, the monthly calendar (Full calendar) does weekly as well, but I think jQuery Week Calendar is better for just a week by week.

Comment: +1 Helpful, thanks.  I suppose I was imprecise with my terminology, but turns out I am looking for a 'datepicker'.

Answer (score 1):

ExtJS includes a calendar example in it's latest incarnation (well, from 3.x onwards), check out the [Samples & demos page](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) to see it in action.

For a full-blown calendar based on ExtJS check out http://ext-calendar.com/. You can switch between different views (daily, weekly, monthly) and create your own. There still are a few bugs to iron out though... (ie. if you select a 2 weeks calendar view and display less then 7 days, the calendar will not render correctly).